# The font of operator names

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath, math-operators, sans-serif

What is the correct way of having all operator names be set in, say, sans serif? Saying

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\sf}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathOperator\operator{operator}
\begin{document}
An $\operator 1$.
\end{document}
```

seems to do the trick, but `amsopn.sty` defines

```
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symoperators}
```

which seems to do more...

It would be nice if there were a `@`-free way of doing this, by the way.

Comment: You need to redefine `\operator@font`, which is used in other macros with *that* name. Either use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` or rewrite `amsopn.sty` in order not to use `\operator@font`. I guess that the choice is easy. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define a new symbol font, and also redefine `\mathsf` to use it, otherwise you'd waste a math group and there are only 16 of them:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{sfoperators}

\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work with unicode-math?

Comment: @arynhard This warrants a new question

Answer (score 1):

You ask in a comment how to get this to work in `unicode-math` and were asked to post [a new question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246304/changing-the-operator-font-with-unicode-math-loaded/605402#605402) For the sake of anyone searching for the answer (or flagging a duplicate question):

To set the operatorfont to something other than `\mathrm`, use, for example:

```
\setoperatorfont\mathsf
```

This also works with math font faces you define with `\setmathfontface`, not only the built-in math alphabets.

To change the `\mathrm` font, use `\setmathrm`.  If you’ll be using it in `\boldmath`, you might also want to `\setboldmathrm`.