# The font of operator names: the size

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

A while ago, I [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43131/the-font-of-operator-names) what was the correct way of changing the font used to set operator names. I stabilized at:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{sfoperators}
\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother
```

Now, the peculiar combination of fonts I am using (Bookman at 11pts, standard cmss) results in the operator names being set in letters which are too small:

[image]

Can I change the fontsize used here?

Answer (score 6):

You can scale up the sans serif font; it's better to use Latin Modern (the shapes are pretty much the same as Computer Modern) for it's scalable without problems:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{slmss}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{slmss}{m}{n}
     {<-8.5> s*[1.1] rm-lmss8
      <8.5-9.5> s*[1.1] rm-lmss9
      <9.5-11> s*[1.1] rm-lmss10
      <11-15.5> s*[1.1] rm-lmss12
      <15.5-> s*[1.1] rm-lmss17
     }{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{OT1}{slmss}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathsf}{sfoperators}
\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother
```

[image]

However, this mixture of Bookman and Computer Modern Math Italic doesn't seem to be very nice.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions of a sans-serif font which matches Bookman better :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I said *nothing* about the sans serif font. It's the math font which doesn't agree at all with Bookman.

Comment: Well, I am open to suggestions in general :)

Comment: There's no math font that agrees with Bookman, at present. You may try the `mathastext` package for getting math in Bookman, but I'm afraid that the results won't be very good in all cases.