Change operator math font with Arial set as the main text font
I want to write a document using Arial as the main text font and mtpro2 lite as the math font.
When I type as follows, everything is as I want, except for the operator font. The sin, cos, log operators appear with Computer Modern font (see the image below), when they should appear with a Times New Roman-based font.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{Arial}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
\[
\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)
\]
Sample text here: $\log(x)=a^b$
\end{document}


When I use Times New Roman as the main text font, the operators are easily displayed as I want.

I have already tried looking around for a solution, but everything seems to fail. What do I need to do in order to change the operator font for Times New Roman?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

welcome! there is no package Arial.sty nor arial.sty in TeX Live. where did you find it? setting the main font only changes the text fonts. the maths fonts are configured separately. it's very unlikely you got operators in TNR. more likely you got serif, which would look more like tnr than arial (but not very like), because you'd be using Latin Modern Roman by default.

you will probably get better results using an opentype maths font for maths with a unicode engine. you really shouldn't use mtpro2 with a unicode engine.


What do I need to do in order to change the operator font [to] Times ... Roman?

The following answer borrows heavily from this answer by @egreg posted in early 2012.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% The following code is adapted from @egreg's answer at 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43135/5001

\DeclareSymbolFont{tmoperators}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{tmoperators}
\makeatletter
\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symtmoperators}
\makeatother
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=0.88] 
% choose roughly equal x-heights for Helvetica/Arial and Times Roman


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
\[
    \sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)
\]
Sample text here: $\log(x)=a^b$
\end{document}


this really isn't a good idea. mtpro2 is not designed to work with unicode engines or fonts. it defines some maths symbols, for example, by testing the default encoding to see whether it is LY1, T1 or OT1. it makes no provision for TU at all.

@cfr - I actually whole-heartedly agree with your view regarding the (non-)advisability of using the mtpro2 package in this way. (The only saving grace is that the ptm text font is extremely basic and is unlikely to cause difficulties when used in the way suggested here. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that the user won't try to use \mathit...) But sometimes you've got to let users waste their own precious time in the wilderness before they feel a need to come to their senses...

well, just excuse me for not giving you a vote on this occasion ;).
